# ODE of two-variable function $u_x=2u(x,y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,y)$ : $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, solve the ODE $u_x = 2u$, or in another form, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2u$.

I know how to solve $\frac{du}{dx}=2u$ when $u$ is $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, but the case when $u$ is two variable function makes me confused.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the PDE $u_x=2u$ is given by $u(x,y)=f(y)e^{2x}$, where $f(y)$ is some arbitrary function independent of $x$. You can show this by using the method of separation of variables, that is let $u(x,y)=A(x)B(y)$ and substitute into the PDE.

Comment: Hi could you be more specific of why we can let $u(x,y)=A(x)B(y)$?

Comment: It is a method to reduce linear PDEs to systems of ordinary differential equations. See [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Analytical_solutions).